# Consistency in length in beam theories

Tags: structural-beam

From my understanding, the Euler Bernoulli Beam theory is mostly used for small angle displacements, and an implication of this assumption is that the length of the beam is subject to distortion and stretching, meaning that when the beam is bent, its length is greater than when relaxed, due to the fact that the end of the rod always remains in line with the end of the rod at equilibrium. The theory thus fails for larger displacements when the change in length of the beam actually affects the result.

Does Timoshenko beam theory suffer from this issue as well? Do beams in Timoshenko theory have consistent length? Are there simple ways of conserving the length of the beam in these theories? Or is the only way to use Geometrically Exact Beam theory and do finite element methods?

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that "the end of the rod always remains in line with the end of the rod at equilibrium". Even if you relax this constraint, the system becomes nonlinear because a vertical load increasingly acts in the axial direction (in addition to the transverse direction). Even if you relax *this* constraint (and allow the load to curve with the end of the beam), nonlinear still arises as various other Euler-Bernoulli assumptions are violated (such as the assumption that cross sections remain undistorted).

Comment: It might be worth considering that the beam isn't just getting longer; it gets shorter as well.  Half the cross section is loaded in tension, the other half in compression.  It's not directly relevant; but it might help see just how much dimensions can distort when you consider realistic bending.